# How to create a MySQL database with Docker for Windows?

Tags: docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker

I'm using Docker for Windows `Version 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139)` with Hyper-V.

I'm trying to restore an existing schema into a Docker container, but keep getting errors.

docker-compoer.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: test
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: testtest
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - ./Schema/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Schema/test.sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test;
USE test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data (
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);
```

When I run:

```
docker-compose up
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: for workspace_mysql_1  Cannot create container for service mysql: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Kyle\Workspace\Schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:rw'

ERROR: for mysql  Cannot create container for service mysql: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\Kyle\Workspace\Schema:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:rw'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I've also tested on Docker for Mac and it appears to work just fine.

Comment: Did you try to mount only the file? ./Schema/test.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/test.sql

Comment: Same error. (well, only differs by the obvious inclusion of the test.sql in the error message)

Answer (score 0):

You need specify the volume name as well in docker-compose.yml , In parallel to services add this

```
    volumes:
     ./Schema/:
```